# TextBox dependiente de un ComboBox

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, wpf

Estoy tratando que un TextBox cambie su contenido dependiendo del item seleccionado del ComboBox. Mi ComboBox genera los items de esta manera...

```
private void cmbNumParte_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string SQL = "SELECT * FROM FamiliasSoluciones";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn);
        conn.Open();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            cmbNumParte.Items.Add(dr["NumeroFamilia"]);
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Lo que intento hacer es que al seleccionar un item de mi ComboBox haga un conteo en una tabla SQLServer de cuantos registros pertenecen a esa familia y que los resultados sean instantáneos y aparezcan en mi TextBox.
Intente hacerlo con Stored Procedures como paso inicial...

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE ContarNumeroFamilia
@NumeroFamilia VARCHAR(3)
AS 
SELECT COUNT (NumeroFamilia) FROM NumerosParte WHERE NumeroFamilia = @NumeroFamilia
GO
```

Cree una clase CD_NumeroFamilia...

```
public void ContarNumeroParte(string NumeroFamilia)
    {
        comando.Connection = conexion.Connection();
        comando.CommandText = "ContarNumeroParte";
        comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumeroFamilia", NumeroFamilia);

        comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

        comando.Parameters.Clear();
        conexion.CloseConnection();
    }
```

y una segunda clase CD_NumeroFamilia

```
public void ContarNumParte(string NumeroParte)
    {
        objetoCD.ContarNumeroParte(NumeroParte);
    }
```

Para finalizar ...

```
private string idnumParte = null;
    CN_NumeroParte numParteCN = new CN_NumeroParte();
    private void CountNumParte()
    {
        ComboBox datos = cmbNumParte.SelectedItem as ComboBox;
        if (datos != null)
        {
            idnumParte = datos.Text;
            numParteCN.ContarNumParte(idnumParte);
        }
    }
```

Lo que no puedo hacer es redireccionar los resultados a mi TextBox para que me aparezcan en cuanto selecciono mi item. Cualquier comentario me ayudaria mucho, incluso si tengo que cambiar de técnica

Comment: Suscribe un evento para que cuando se cambie la selección se consulte la base de datos y se actualice el textbox.

Comment: Como adicion a lo que dijo @Mateo sugiero usar el evento selectionChanged()

Comment: Yo sugiero SelectedValueChanged o SelectedIndexChanged https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox?view=windowsdesktop-7.0